# VBA Recordsets: Why does the way I declare my array, in the Fieldvalue parameters of .addnew, matter?

Tags: vba, adodb, recordset

I've been trying to dynamically add to a Recordset but I am unable to do so. The .addnew function of a adodb.recordset seems to not allow just any type of array to be passed to it's fieldvalues, values parameters. For example if after setting up your recordset with the appropriate field values you say:

```
 FieldsArray = array("field1", "field2")
 ValuesArray = array("val1","val2")

 rs.AddNew FieldsArray, ValuesArray
```

This works!!
But if you instead write

```
 Dim fieldsarray(0 To 1) As String
 FieldsArray(0) = "field1"
 FieldsArray(1) = "field2"
 ValuesArray = array("val1","val2")

 rs.AddNew FieldsArray, ValuesArray
```

It Fails?!?! (More specifically [Run-Time error '3001': Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another])

Why does the way one declares the field array in the .addnew parameters matter? Is there a way I can get the latter to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in the first example you are declaring two arrays of `VARIANT` data type, while in the second example you are declaring `STRING` arrays.

The AddNew function is expecting a variant array.

In you second example, change your first line to:

```
Dim fieldsarray(0 To 1) As Variant
```

and it should work.

Comment: <3 Yeah I am so glad it is a simple answer. Thank you :)

Comment: How do you find out the expected type of functions like that?